# Can I store my user defined datatypes into Azure Database?

Tags: c#, database, azure

I have defined a class and i need to store some objects of that class for future reference. Can i store these objects into an azure database i've created ?

Comment: Need more details. Off the top of my head, you could serialize your object, you could have columns for the specific fields that get serialized into your class (how most ORMs work). You could encode the values, for example a bitmask, if it's true/false values. Etc.

Comment: I am using a Token sort of a class from an existing API .. i need to store that token. I cannot get the token value as a string hence i need to store the whole object.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't store objects, you'd store a serialization of an instance.  If you using Azure SQL you could use some sort of mapper to map an instance (serialize) into columns in a table.  If you're using Azure Tables you effectively serialize to XML then store that in the table (although the SDK can hide that fact).  If you're using Azure DocumentDB you effectively serialize your instance to JSON and store that as a document in the database.

Comment: More details around your Token Class would be great, can you post code?

Answer (score -1):

In order to save an object (instance of a Class) to whatever medium (SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure Table Storage, Blob Storage, local File System, whatever you come up with), you will need to [serialize it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.110).aspx). Then store the result of serialization to the medium of your choice. Next, when you want to use the persisted state of the object, you will have to deserialize it.

There are different serialization formatters, like XML, JSON, Binary, etc. Which one to use, depends on the where and how you are going to store the object. The most important however, is that, in order one object to be serialized, the defining Class should be marked with [SerializableAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute(v=vs.110).aspx). And the drama begins when you want to serialize object which is part of 3rd partys API.

If it is your type - just mark it as Serializbale, serialize and store it. Pretty stright-forward process.

If you don't have access to the source code to explicitly mark class as Serializable, you could possibly use the [Serialization Surrogate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166105/is-it-possible-to-do-net-binary-serialization-of-an-object-when-you-dont-have) to serialize your object. But, you might have issues when deserializing. For example, if the API Class you use does not have a public contructor. Or if it does not provide setters for some of the properties, etc., etc. At the end, if a Type is not designed to be serializable, and is part of 3rd party API, there might be a ton of reasons serialization/deserialization might fail.

At the end, you could try using the Json.NET serializer ([install via NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)):

```
        var someObj = new DummyClass
        {
            ID = Guid.NewGuid(),
            IntID = 102934,
            Name = "My Super Hero Name"
        };

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObj);
        Console.WriteLine(json);

        var otherObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DummyClass>(json);

        Console.WriteLine(otherObj.ID);

        Console.ReadKey();
```

and check if it correctly serializes/deserializes your object. If everything is fine - use the json string to save it into Database of your choice.

Comment: Another awesome and really appropriate downvote! Keep it coming, you may at the end have very interesting community! It is especially useful to downvote answers to questions provided more than two years ago. Excellent job!