# Deserializtion return empty object, using Filestream and Binary Formatter

Tags: c#, filestream, binaryformatter

The problem is that i get zero count in repo when deserialize it (without any errors)

```
[Serializable]
class RegexRepository : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public RegexRepository()
    {
        //this.Add("All", "ALL");
        //this.Add("Name", @"Name:(?<data>[\s\w]+)Email");
        //this.Add("Email", @"Email:(?<data>[\w\s@]+\.com)");
        //this.Add("Phone Number", "Phone:(?<data>\\d+)");
    }
    protected RegexRepository(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {

    }
    private static RegexRepository repo = new RegexRepository();
    public static RegexRepository Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (repo == null)
            {
                repo = new RegexRepository();
            }
            return repo;
        }
    }
    string FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "BinaryFile.dat";
    public void Serialize()
    {
        using (FileStream ms = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(ms, this);
        }
    }
    public void Deserialize()
    {
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(FileName))
        {
            using (FileStream ms = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                repo = (RegexRepository)bf.Deserialize(ms);
               //Here i get zero count in repo, checked while debugging
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have seen **BinaryFile.dat** is not empty and i can see some records in it. Kindly help me

Comment: I guess you are having this issue because the Dictionary class that you have derived from is not marked as serializable. In this case I think you need a surrogate. This may be your [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166105/is-it-possible-to-do-net-binary-serialization-of-an-object-when-you-dont-have). The question is do you really need to derive your class from the Dictionary class?

Comment: @KosalaW -  `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is serializable.  See the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs).

Comment: @KosalaW it will be easy for me if i don't use derived class? kindly check answer of dbc. he says that i don't need filename. How?

Comment: @Charlie - What I meant is that it doesn't need to be an instance field. See updated answer.

Comment: @Charlie: Yes. Just checked. dbcc is correct. Dictionary is [serializable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx). So you need to call the base constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the base constructor from your streaming constructor:

```
    protected RegexRepository(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context)
    {
    }
```

Also, `FileName` probably should not be a field, you're allocating memory for it in your class, which is not necessary.  Instead a static property would seem to make more sense:

```
    static string FileName
    {
        get
        {
            return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "BinaryFile.dat";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When the base class implements ISerializable, it isn't enough to just slap a [Serializable] attribute on a derived class. Your derived class needs to:

1. Call base(info, context) from the (currently empty) serialization constructor.
2. Fill in your serialization constructor to read any instance values from the SerializationInfo.
3. Create a `GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)` override to write derived members to SerializationInfo (and call the base class' implementation).

Running VS code analysis on your class will light up the problems.