# C# storing temporary data for serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

I am implementing a hierarchy of classes that use .NET's built in serialization. Due to the nature of most of these classes and the way .NET handles deserialization with a graph deserializer, I need to store temporary data somewhere and wait for it to be fully deserialized.

My classes all currently include something similar to the following:

```
class Example : ISerializable
{
  private readonly dynamic _serialData = new ExpandoObject();

  public ulong Id { get; private set; }
  public string[] Strings { get; private set; }

  protected Example( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
  {
    _serialData.Id = info.GetValue( nameof( Id ), typeof( ulong ) );
    _serialData.Strings = info.GetValue( nameof( Strings ), typeof( string[] ) );
  }

  public void GetObjectData( SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context )
  {
    info.AddValue( nameof( Id ), Id );
    info.AddValue( nameof( Strings ), Strings );
  }

  [OnDeserialized]
  private void OnDeserialized( StreamingContext context )
  {
    Id = _serialData.Id;
    Strings = _serialData.Strings;
  }

}
```

I realize that the `OnDeserialized()` method can sometimes be redundant for primitives and other non-enumerable types, but I am trying to keep everything uniform with the more complex classes that have references to child classes and so on.

**With that, here's my question:**

I currently store the temporary data in the `_serialData` field. Once it is deserialized, there is no need for this field anymore. I could easily just clear the field once deserialization is complete, but I would much rather have it stored somewhere as a scoped variable that is garbage collected when it is no longer needed.

I see that the `StreamingContext` is passed along with the serialization constructor and methods, but I don't really understand what it is used for, and I don't see any way to store temporary data in it.

**Is there a way I can avoid having `_serialData` as a class field entirely?**

Comment: *.NET's built in serialization* - are you referring to `BinaryFormatter`?

Comment: @dbc Yes, my objects implement `ISerializable` and I am currently using BinaryFormatter to serialize and deserialize the data.

Comment: Then you could use a serialization surrogate.  See e.g. [Is it possible to do .NET binary serialization of an object when you don't have the source code of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16121346).

Answer (score 1):

The first and easiest thing that comes to mind is a static `ConditionalWeakTable` ([See docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.conditionalweaktable-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)). You can also periodically check the table to see which objects are still alive, and remove the garbage collected objects from the table. Or in the `destructor` of the objects, get them to remove themselves from the table.